# Model test giving more data than expected for my has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a group that can have many billing companies.
I have  billing company that can have many groups.  So i created a join table migration and added this in each of the models:

group.rb:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base

    #I have to figure out how providers will be held in this app if its going to be an intermediary table or what.  Does deleting a provider from a group remove them
    #from the db all together or just that group?

    #validations
    validates :group_name, presence: true


    #associations

    #i think my issue is here, I have a lot of providers through provider_locations but there is no way to tell a group that provider_locations and group_locations are linked.
    has_many :group_locations
    has_many :providers, through: :provider_locations
    has_many :provider_locations, through: :group_locations
    has_many :invoices
    has_and_belongs_to_many :billings
    has_many :addresses, through: :group_locations



    belongs_to  :billing_address, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: 'billing_address_id'
    belongs_to  :mailing_address, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: 'mailing_address_id'
    has_and_belongs_to_many :insurances
    #has_many :provider_locations, through: :group_locations


end
```

And billing.rb:

```
class Billing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end
```

I thought I was finally understanding associations but in my billing test.  I add a billing company to two different groups and then when I try to get all the billing companies, it returns three.  It should return one with two groups under it.  I am not understanding why this is.  My test code is here:

```
  require 'test_helper'


class BillingTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

    def setup


        puts Billing.delete_all  #shows 2
        puts 'First count'
        puts Billing.all.count #shows 0
        puts 'End of count'


        @group = Group.create(group_name: 'My Awesome', group_contact: 'pbs@myawesome.com', tin: '382FSJ2', npi: '2301329', notes: 'group was termed but then reinstated')
        adr = Address.create(city: 'Las Cruces', state: 'New Mexico', zip: '88012', address_line_one: '382 Dark Side of the Moon', address_line_two: '')
        gl =GroupLocation.create(group: @group, address: adr)
        adr2 = Address.create(city: 'Albuquerque', state: 'New Mexico', zip: '88012', address_line_one: '1310 Constitution NE', address_line_two: '')
        @group.mailing_address = adr2
        @provider = Provider.create(first_name: 'Shane', last_name: 'Thomas')
        pl = ProviderLocation.create(provider: @provider, group_location: gl)


         @group2 = Group.create(group_name: 'My Other Group', group_contact: 'pbs@myothergroup.com', tin: '312fsf', npi: '412512', notes: '')
        adr2 = Address.create(city: 'Las Cruces', state: 'New Mexico', zip: '88012', address_line_one: '381 Far Side of the Moon', address_line_two: '')

        gl2 =GroupLocation.create(group: @group2, address: adr2)
        adr3 = Address.create(city: 'Albuquerque', state: 'New Mexico', zip: '88012', address_line_one: '1310 Constitution NE', address_line_two: '')
        @group2.mailing_address = adr3
        @provider2 = Provider.create(first_name: 'Shane', last_name: 'Thomas')
        p2 = ProviderLocation.create(provider: @provider2, group_location: gl2)



        @billing = Billing.create(name: 'Marcha billing company', contact: 'bob@marcha.com')
        @billing.address = Address.create(city: 'Las Cruces', state: 'New Mexico', zip: '88012', address_line_one: '501 Search-Bloc Rd', address_line_two: '')

        @group.billings << @billing #add this billing to a group.
        @group2.billings << @billing

        puts 'Last count'
        puts Billing.all.count  #shows 1
        puts 'End of Last count'


    end

    test 'retreiving all the groups for a billing company' do
        puts Billing.all.count #shows 1
        Billing.all.each do | bill |
            if bill.groups.count > 0
                puts bill.groups.first.group_name
            end
        end 
    end


end
```

EDIT: Added some print statements, no idea why this sucker starts up with 2 bills exsisting.  I can delete them all, add the one bill everything looks good count wise.  Re-run the test and it is the same thing everytime starts with two bills exsisting. So I also printed out the name of the first bill.  It was MyText.  I used agent ransack to search my project folder for this it appears a lot.  Namely in a billings.yml fixture.

```
# Read about fixtures at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

one:
  name: MyText
  contact: MyText
  address_id: 

two:
  name: MyText
  contact: MyText
  address_id:
```

I guess fixtures are a way to get data stood up for testing fast.  I am a bit nervous to use them since a lot of my has and belong to manys  use join tables and no idea how those fixtures would work since the ID's would have to match for consistent testing.  It looks like I can make the list ordered in the fixture though so I guess that works.

If I wanted to just keep using my setup data though and NOT the fixtures, is there a quick way to shut them off?

Comment: Use byebug and look at what's in the billing objects, and see if that gives you a clue as to where they came from.  A previous test run?  Auto-created  when you made the groups?

Comment: Edited my answer.  Basically I just used some 'print' statements to test.  Odd results posted above.